# Take Snapshot for Embed Video using Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, embed, vlc

I am using VLC web plugin to display video. It could be locally saved video or coming via RTSP. Below is the code

```
<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" width="640" height="480" id="vlc" events="True">
<param name="MRL" value="someRTSP" />
<param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
<param name="AutoLoop" value="False" />
<param name="AutoPlay" value="False" />
<param name="Volume" value="50" />
<param name="toolbar" value="true" />
<param name="StartTime" value="0" />
<EMBED pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
       type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
       version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
       width="640"
       height="480"
       toolbar="true"
       loop="true"
       text="Waiting for video"
       target="someRTSP"
       name="vlc">
</EMBED>
</object>
```

As [this](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/) doc suggest, I tried taking snapshot of video using its property `vlc.video.takeSnapshot()`, but it dont seem to be working. So I tried using canvas for the same

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
<button id="snap" onclick="snap()">Snap Photo</button> 

 <script>
function getVLC(name)
{
    if (window.document[name])
    {
        return window.document[name];
    }
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1)
    {
        if (document.embeds && document.embeds[name])
            return document.embeds[name];
    }
    else // if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")!=-1)
    {
        return document.getElementById(name);
    }
}
     var vlc = getVLC("vlc");
     var canvas=document.querySelector('canvas');
     var context=canvas.getContext('2d');

     var w,h,ratio;
        //add loadedmetadata which will helps to identify video attributes
          video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',function()
          {
          ratio=video.videoWidth/video.videoHeight;
          w=video.videoWidth-100;
          h=parseInt(w/ratio,10);
          canvas.width=w;
          canvas.height=h;
          },false);

         function snap()
        {
              context.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
          context.drawImage(video,0,0,w,h);
          }
    </script>
```

How can I take snapshot using VLC property and if not how do I make it work using canvas ?

Comment: @MichalHainc, question updated. It will grab the embed object.

Answer (score 1):

According to official VLC documentation (https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aWebPlugin) the

```
vlc.video.takeSnapshot()
```

is available only in ActiveX, thus only in Internet Explorer / Edge (I tested it and it works... but anyway it is saving snaphot image files to the user's desktop).

Trying to capture the video - the canvas way - I failed.
The video element must be rendered by the browser in the html5 mode, not by a 3rd party browser plugin like the VLC plugin.

The DOM element that you try to pass as parameter to the

```
canvas.drawImage()
```

must derive from one of:

```
HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement, ImageBitmap
```

not from

```
object, embed
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs but I faced following issues.

1) It works in IE, but I could not find the saved image on desktop or in My Pictures folder
2) It does not work in Firefox even though VLC web plugin is installed in Firefox. Thus technically it should work in FF as well apart from IE.
3) Is it possible to change image format and its location ?

Comment: Pls try this ignoring `addEventListener`.  `<input type=button id="snap" value=" Snapshot " onClick='doSnap();'>
function doSnap(){
    var vlc = getVLC("vlc");
    vlc.video.takeSnapshot();
}`

Comment: Ref - http://people.videolan.org/~dionoea/vlc-plugin-demo/plugin.php?url=rtsp://people.videolan.org:5554/storewars3&width=320&height=180&plugin=activex

Comment: True. It indeed works in IE. But it does not in Firefox. Also is there any option available to  change saved image path and type ? What could be an alternate soln for FF that does not supports activex ?

Comment: I tired changing snapshot path and image type, but it has not effect on web plugin. Canvas is not working with embed object. Thus can we conclude that `vlc.video.takeSnapshot();` would work ONLY in IE and not in FF.

Comment: I am playing RTSP video usign VLC web plugin in IE and FF and adding snapshot feature to it. But as discussed, it works on IE but not in FF.